# How to make LLM using tensorflow for array classification?

Tags: tensorflow

I have below set of data -

```json
[
    {
        id: 1,
        array: ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4'] 
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        array: ['str1', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7', 'str8', 'str11']
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        array: ['str1', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7', 'str9', 'str10']
    }
]
```

Here array size is not fixed. Now, I want to match array like below -

1. input - ['str1', 'str5', 'str3'] then basis on the last element it should return id 1
2. input - ['str1', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7'] then basis on the sequence it should return any of id 2 or 3
3. input - ['str1', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7','str8'] then basis on the sequence it should return- id 2

Also, I want matching score if possible.

I have tried below code but it is not working -

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import json
import numpy as np

# Opening JSON file
f = open('CFT_28.json')
 
# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f);
# Closing file
f.close();

dataset = []
for obj in data:
    dataset.append({
        "convId": obj["convId"],
        "conversation": obj["conversation"]
    });
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

# Create an LLM model.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    #tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000, output_dim=128),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(None, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Train the model.
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(df, epochs=10) // Getting error
```

Here getting error below -
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).

I want to create LLM model on array type data, I have tried creating as said in problem statement but not succeed.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why would you need to train an LLM on this -not to mention on this specific format-. If you have an LLM, get embeddings and compare every array element-wise with your input array, return the highest ranking array and as a bonus you'd have a matching score.

Comment: Because I have a large set of predefined arrays.

Comment: If they're predefined, gettings embeddings is even easier. Your comment doesn't explain the need of training an LLM.